# area chart not able render D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3.js and this is me trying to learn area chart but i am getting this error of :

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  /* set the CSS */

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .area {
    fill: green;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%B %e, %Y");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the area
    var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.Date);
      })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function (d) {
        return y(d["New cases"]);
      });

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3
      .line()
      .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.newcases);
      });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // get the data
    d3.csv(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pravinpoudel/file-host/main/COVID-Utah.csv"
    ).then(function (data) {
      // format the data
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.Date = parseTime(d.Date);
        d["New cases"] = +d["New cases"];
      });

      x.domain(
        d3.extent(data, function (d) {
          return d.Date;
        })
      );
      y.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d["New cases"];
        }),
      ]);

      // add the area
      svg.append("path").data([data]).attr("class", "area").attr("d", area);

      // add the valueline path.
      svg
        .append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

      // add the X Axis
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

can anyone please help me on this !!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer, so let me try and pitch in.

The biggest issue is how you append the `<path>` elements for the area and line.

```js
svg.append("path").data([data]).attr("class", "area").attr("d", area);

svg.append("path").data([data]).attr("class", "line").attr("d", valueline);
```

Once you append the `<path>` element you instead need to pass the data in the `area` and `valueline` functions.

```js
svg.append("path").attr("class", "area").attr("d", area(data));

svg.append("path").attr("class", "line").attr("d", valueline(data));
```

Unfortunately this is not enough, and the console points you to the error.

```bash
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…5.1232876712329,NaNL882.68493150…"
```

Some coordinates are assigned a value of `NaN`, and looking at the data this has to do with the `New cases` field. The value is not always a number, often `NaN` or `N/A`. As a workaround you can try the conversion and provide a fallback.

```
d["New cases"] = +d["New cases"]
+d["New cases"] = +d["New cases"] || 0;
```

It's a bit of a judgment call, however. You need to decide how to interpret data points which do not have an available value.

With these two changes you finally are able to display the area, but not the line. Looking at the definition of `valueline` it seems you point to two different properties.

```js
var valueline = d3
  .line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.newcases);
  });
```

Be sure to reference the properties of the data, as you have done with the area function.

```
-return x(d.date);
+return x(d.Date);

-return y(d.newcases);
+return y(d['New cases']);
```

As the line and area have the same color you might find it difficult to distinguish them visually, but they are both plotted.

---

A minor note on the name of the `svg` variable.

```js
var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

As you mention in the comment you append a group element to translate the origin. This means the variable refers to the group element, and not the svg.

Hope it helps.